# How to get an image from a long string data in dm-script

Tags: dm-script

I would like to get an image data from a string data array.
The below script runs well but speed is low.
(The actual length of the string data is much longer than in the example below.)
I guess pixel addressing in the for loop would take a time.

```
image str2img(string str)
{
    image img:=RealImage("",4,10,1)
    string tempstr=str
    for(number i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(find(tempstr,",")!=-1)
        {
            img[i,0]=tempstr.left(find(tempstr,",")).val()
            tempstr=tempstr.right(tempstr.len()-find(tempstr,",")-1)
            result(tempstr+"\n")
        }else
        {
            img[i,0]=tempstr.val()
        }
    }
    return img
}

string input="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
image output=str2img(input)
output.showimage()
```

Then I wrote the following script to use stream.
However I got the error massage 'Non-numeric text encountered'.

```
image str2img(string str)
{
    TagGroup Tg=NewTagGroup()
    Tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString("data",str)
    
    object fstream=NewStreamFromBuffer(0)
    TagGroupWriteTagDataToStream(Tg,"data",fstream,0)
    fstream.StreamSetPos(0,0)

    number bLinesAreRows=1
    number bSizeByCount=1 
    number dtype=2 //2 for real4 (float)
    object imgSizeObj = Alloc( "ImageData_ImageDataSize" )
    image img := ImageImportTextData( "Imag Name " , fstream , dtype , imgSizeObj , bLinesAreRows , bSizeByCount )
    return img
}

string input="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
image output=str2img(input)
output.showimage()
```

Is the "ImageImportTextData()" function valid only for reading a saved file?

Or are there any efficient way to obtain an image from a long string data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good question and I like they way you were going about it.
No, `ImageImportTextData()` works for any stream as you will see in the example below.
However, the command requires text-lines to be finalized by line-breaks if you want it to count, and there seems to be an issue with String-tags streaming. I never use this, as there are dedicated commands to stream text.

So, your fixed script looks like:

---

```c
image str2img(string str)
{
    object fstream=NewStreamFromBuffer(0)
    fStream.StreamWriteAsText(0,str)  // Write text to stream directly
    fstream.StreamSetPos(0,0)

    number bLinesAreRows=1
    number bSizeByCount=1 
    number dtype=2 //2 for real4 (float)
    object imgSizeObj = Alloc( "ImageData_ImageDataSize" )
    
    image img := ImageImportTextData( "Imag Name " , fstream , dtype , imgSizeObj , bLinesAreRows , bSizeByCount )
    return img
}

string input="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\n" // Note final line-break if you want to count.
image output=str2img(input)
output.showimage()
```

Comment: Is there a similar function to do the reverse? Like ImageExportTextData() to a stream object (like a memory buffer)? I can use SaveAsText() but it is still kind of slow.

Comment: @KEVIVI SaveAsText() is likely as fast as you can go - the same speed as using the File menu "SaveAs". It's just horrendously inefficient to save big number arrays as ASCII text :c)  What is the use case anyway? Other than exporting as CVS for Excel, I see very little value in storing numbers as text files.

Comment: Yes, it's for importing text data, processed in DM and then exporting data as text for other program. Data set of 400x250x10 will take almost 50 second to export using SaveAsText(). Just wonder if there is a faster way.

Comment: @KEVIVI of course it depends on the other program's import capabilities, but I would always go for a two-file solution in that case: Raw binary number format plus text-file with accompanying information. Of course, if you know the file structure the other program requires, you can also write a binary export script in that format. I did this with Matlab files f.e. (and import for TIF + meta-info)